# Infinite loop when catching error from BehaviorSubject subscribed by async pipe on Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, infinite-loop, rxjs, observable

I have an rxjs `BehaviorSubject` I subscribe to using an `async` pipe from Angular 2 and I have a `catch` to handle eventual errors it throws.
Problem is, every time I get an error it starts an infinite loop because my catch returns the Observable derived from the `BehaviorSubject` and I think the `async` pipe resubscribes to the observable when I return the `catch`.

The code looks roughly like this:

**ListService** - is a `@Injectable` where I have the BehaviorSubject and the property with the `Observable`.

```
private listSubject: BehaviorSubject<IItem[]>;

public get listObservable() {
    return this.listSubject.asObservable()
}

private error(error: IError) {
    this.listSubject.error(error);
}
```

**ListComponent** - is a `@Component` that shows the list observable.

```
// Template
<items-view [items]="list | async"></items-view>

// Code
public get list() {
    return this.listService.listObservable
        .catch((error) => {
            this.handleError(error);
            return this.listService.listObservable;
        });
}
```

As you can see, my catch returns the current observable, as it MUST return an observable. So, what happens is, when I send the `this.listSubject.error(error)` the code enters an infinite loop calling the `catch` indefinitely because, like I said before, I think that the `BehaviourSubject` re-throws the error because the `async` pipe re-subscribes to the observable when the `catch` returns it.

I tried to return my previous cached array in the error to return an `Observable.of(error.cached)`, but I got a whole new set of problems because think the async wasn't subscribed to the `BehaviorSubject` anymore.

Like I said before, this is a rough representation of my real code, but the logic is basically that.

I have been trying various different approaches to this but I couldn't manage to get this infinite loop to stop.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is the type of error that get's thrown and what do you expect your code to do in the case of an error?

Comment: Any error, I pass the error using that error function in the List service, even if I just pass a string I'll have the problem. But usually I pass api response errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a generally bad idea to manually dispatch an error on a Subject, that is supposed to only eject data (like the `BehaviorSubject` in your case). The reason is, that when an error occurs on a `Subject`, the `Subject` is essentially *dead* -> meaning, that no new data can be ejected on it any more. This is one of the core-concepts of rxjs. Here is a small example:

```
let stream$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1);

stream$.subscribe(x => console.log("Logging: " + x), e => console.error("Error: " + e)); // logs 1, 2, Error: ...

stream$.next(2);
stream$.error(new Error("Some error message."));
stream$.next(3); // this will have no effect, because the stream is "dead"
stream$.subscribe(x => console.log("Logging 2: " + x), e => console.error("Error: " + e)); // this will just log the error
```

For your case this means that you did some error-handling, but then just return the "old, dead, error"-Subject - in other words: propagate the error down the stream. (I'm not assuming that `handleError()` creates a fresh `Subject`, which would be an awful practice anyways.)

In general it means that `.error` should only be used for streams that perform a defined operation and have a defined number of results and then complete or throw an error, but not on `Subject`s that you want to emit data throughout the complete lifetime of the application.

How to solve this in your case: The quick&dirty (really dirty!!) way would be to use two separate Subjects, one for the data and one for errors (eject with `.next`).

**The proper fix**: Split up your architecture into a data-generation-flow and into a data-store-part.

The lifecycle would look something like this:

**Generative Flow**

1. Some Event (e.g. a Button-Click, or some Timebased Event)
2. Service.generateOrFetchData().handleErrors()
3. StoreService.someSubj.next(data) - (step 3 could be optional, depending on how you want to handle errors in step 2)

**Subscribing Flow**

1. UI Subscribes to StoreService.someSubj
2. UI automatically updates whenever new data is ejected, no error-handling required

---

The **perfect** fix would be to use a ready-to-use thought-through store-architecture like [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store), however implementing this in an existing project will come with major refactoring requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I went with the dirty fix for now, I'll get back to this once I finish what I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: In the proper fix, are you mentioning that we use only one observable and differentiate success and error scenario's based on data?

Comment: At least just one Observable for the relevant data and the Error-Handling outside of that observable (it COULD be another observable)